# Time Zone Issue in CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I am using CRM Online 2013 and develop the code for connector in my local custom application, but during the implementation of code, it gives the following error:

> {"The security timestamp is stale because its expiration time ('2014-10-07T15:07:01.000Z') is in the past. Current time is '2014-10-08T04:22:49.109Z' and allowed clock skew is '00:05:00'."}

I made that time zone of Server and Client the same, but I am facing the similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is not in your code, the date on your end is wrong. Once the date on your end is correct CRM will stop complaining.

If you are developing inside a VM, make sure that the Guest machine is correct (it might not be synced with the Host)

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem the other day and it looks like the timezone is UTC but the WCF settings don't let you go past 5 mins as it think there is a sync issue. This is what we did.

*ADFS is impacted  because it was 5 mins 5 sec ahead and it was generating security token that was ahead with XRM-SERVER server time. Corrected this time and WCF service was able to function as intended.*

Also check to see if the auto sync. time on servers is messed up and is syncing time ahead of 5 mins timebound range.